# ERROR in Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported -- Failed to compile

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

**Current behavior**

When I try to run my Webpack dev server, compilation fails and I get the following output :

```
...
 [0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 whatwg-fetch 40 bytes {polyfills} [built]
 [2] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./samples/allsymbols/main.js 40 bytes {allsymbols} [built]
 [3] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./samples/balloons/main.js 40 bytes {balloons} [built]
 [4] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./samples/camera/main.js 40 bytes {camera} [built]
 [5] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./samples/clustering/main.js 40 bytes {clustering} [built]
 [6] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./samples/complexstroking/main.js 40 bytes {complexstroking} [built]
 [7] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./samples/constructivegeometry/main.js 40 bytes {constructivegeometry} [built]
 [8] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./samples/createedit/main.js 40 bytes {createedit} [built]
 [9] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./samples/data/main.js 40 bytes {data} [built]
[10] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./samples/dataformats/main.js 40 bytes {dataformats} [built]
[11] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./samples/dualmap/main.js 40 bytes {dualmap} [built]
[12] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./samples/ecdis/main.js 40 bytes {ecdis} [built]
[13] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./samples/extrudedshapes/main.js 40 bytes {extrudedshapes} [built]
[14] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./samples/firstsample/main.js 40 bytes {firstsample} [built]
[15] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./samples/googleimage/main.js 40 bytes {googleimage} [built]
    + 1102 hidden modules

WARNING in new Worker() will only be bundled if passed a String.
 @ ./lib/luciad/view/strategy/PhotonViewPaintingStrategy.js 28:0-78 104:35-58 111:49-72
 @ ./lib/luciad/view/WebGLMap.js
 @ ./samples/reprojection/main.js

ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported


ERROR in   Error: HTML5 Canvas is not supported

Child HtmlWebpackCompiler:
     32 assets
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_0 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_0
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_1 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_1
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_2 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_2
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_3 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_3
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_4 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_4
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_5 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_5
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_6 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_6
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_7 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_7
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_8 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_8
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_9 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_9
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_10 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_10
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_11 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_11
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_12 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_12
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_13 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_13
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_14 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_14
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_15 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_15
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_16 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_16
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_17 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_17
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_18 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_18
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_19 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_19
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_20 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_20
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_21 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_21
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_22 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_22
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_23 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_23
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_24 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_24
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_25 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_25
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_26 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_26
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_27 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_27
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_28 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_28
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_29 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_29
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_30 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_30
    Entrypoint HtmlWebpackPlugin_31 = __child-HtmlWebpackPlugin_31
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./samples/allsymbols/main.js] 9.85 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_0} [built]
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./samples/balloons/main.js] 1.84 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_1} [built]    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./samples/camera/main.js] 5.5 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_2} [built]
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./samples/clustering/main.js] 4.41 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_3} [built]
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./samples/complexstroking/main.js] 2.94 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_4} [built]
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./samples/constructivegeometry/main.js] 5.21 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_5} [built]
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./samples/createedit/main.js] 7.27 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_6} [built]
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./samples/data/main.js] 2.87 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_7} [built]
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./samples/dataformats/main.js] 34.4 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_8} [built]
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./samples/dualmap/main.js] 8.75 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_9} [built]
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./samples/ecdis/main.js] 1.66 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_10} [built]
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./samples/extrudedshapes/main.js] 3.81 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_11} [built]
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./samples/firstsample/main.js] 3.5 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_12} [built]
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./samples/googleimage/main.js] 1.94 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_13} [built]
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./samples/googlemaps/main.js] 2.21 KiB {HtmlWebpackPlugin_14} [built]
        + 1037 hidden modules

    WARNING in new Worker() will only be bundled if passed a String.
     @ ./lib/luciad/view/strategy/PhotonViewPaintingStrategy.js 28:0-78 104:35-58 111:49-72
     @ ./lib/luciad/view/WebGLMap.js
     @ ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./samples/reprojection/main.js
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

**Configuration**

I have the following folder structure :
[image: Folder structure]

My `package.json` contains the following setup :

```
{
  "name": "ria-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Sample project demonstrating RIA integration with webpack",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "Luciad NV",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.2",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "exports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "glob": "^7.1.4",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.5",
    "raw-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1",
    "worker-plugin": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 NODE_ENV=development webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "build:prod": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 NODE_ENV=production webpack --config webpack.config.js",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 NODE_ENV=devserver webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js"
  }
}
```

My `webpack.config.json` contains the following setup :

```js
const isDevserver = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'devserver';
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const path = require('path');

const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const WorkerPlugin = require('worker-plugin');
const glob = require("glob");

const files = glob.sync("./samples/**/main.js", {nodir : true}).reduce((accumulator, fileName) => {
    const sampleName = path.basename(path.dirname(fileName));
    const relativeFileName = path.relative("./samples", fileName);
    accumulator.entry[sampleName] = fileName;
    accumulator.plugins.push(new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: fileName,
      chunks: ['polyfills', sampleName],
      filename: relativeFileName
    }));
    return accumulator;
}, { 
  entry : {
      polyfills : ["whatwg-fetch"]
  }, 
  plugins : [...(isDevserver ? [] : [new CleanWebpackPlugin({})]),
    new WorkerPlugin({
      // use "self" as the global object when receiving hot updates.
      globalObject: 'self' // <-- this is the default value
    }),
    new CopyPlugin([{
        from: 'samples/resources',
        to: 'resources'
      }])]
});

module.exports = {
  mode: isDevelopment ? 'development' : 'production',
  entry: files.entry,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.txt$/i,
        loader: 'raw-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['to-string-loader'].concat(ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader', options: {
                minimize: true,
                sourceMap: true
              }
            }
          ]
        }))
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: { minimize: !isDevelopment }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: require.resolve('./samples/template/init.js'),
        use: 'exports-loader?resetMapSize,disableUI,UILoaded,queryParameters,bootstrapUI'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: [{
          loader: 'file-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]'
          }
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.css'],
    modules: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'samples'),
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
        'node_modules'
      ]
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  output: {
    filename: isDevelopment ? '[name].js' : '[name].[hash].js'
  },
  optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all'
    }
  },
  plugins: files.plugins
};
```

The lib folder contains only the LuciadRIA JavaScript library which I am unfortunately not allowed to share here.

The sample folder contains mostly sub-folders that contain at least an `index.html` and a `main.js`.

One of the most basic samples has the following HTML...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
      <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
      <title>Balloon</title>
      <link href="../../samples/template/css/sample-single.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   </head>
   <body class="categorymixed allowcanvas allowwebgl allow3D">
      <div id="map">
         <div class="logo" id="logo"></div>
         <div class="topcenter" id="toasts"></div>
         <div id="onmap"></div>
         <div id="topleftbuttons">
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-map homepage-button" href="https://hexagon.com/" role="button" target="_blank" title="Homepage">
               <span class="lcdIcon lcdIconLogoHexagon-bug"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-map info-button" role="button" title="More info">
               <span class="glyphicon"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-map fullscreen-button" role="button" title="Fullscreen">
               <span class="glyphicon"></span>
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="infopanel">
         <div id="infopanel-content">
            <h1>Balloon</h1>
            <p>
      The Balloon sample illustrates the use of balloon widgets on the map.
      The contents of a balloon can be specified with a string or with valid HTML.
    </p>
            <p>
               Add balloons to the map by using the
               <code>showBalloon()</code>
               method. Remove them from the map by calling
               <code>hideBalloon()</code>
               .
            </p>
            <p>
      The contents of a balloon can be specified with a string or with valid HTML.
    </p>
            <p>
      Balloons can be anchored to an object (for instance, a Feature from the model which is visualized by a
      FeatureLayer). Updates of the location of the feature cause the balloon to update as well.
    </p>
            <p>
               Balloons are styled with the
               <code>samples/common/balloon/luciad-balloon.css</code>
               style-sheet. This stylesheet may be replaced with your own custom stylesheet.
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="messageoverlay">
         <h3>
            <span id="messageoverlaytext"></span>
            <br>
            <a href="#" id="messageoverlaylink"></a>
         </h3>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

And it has the following JS code :

```js
import PaintRepresentation from "luciad/view/PaintRepresentation";
import LayerConfigUtil from "../common/LayerConfigUtil";
import sampleTemplate from "../template/sample";

  var map = sampleTemplate.makeMap();
  var smallWorldLayer = LayerConfigUtil.addWorldLayer(map);

  // CITIES
  var citiesLayer = LayerConfigUtil.addCitiesLayer(map);
  citiesLayer.setPaintRepresentationVisible(PaintRepresentation.LABEL, false);

  LayerConfigUtil.addLonLatGridLayer(map);

  //#snippet ballooncontentprovider
  function contentProvider(prefix, property) {
    return function(o) {
      return prefix + (o.properties[property] || "no property");
    };
  }

  //#endsnippet ballooncontentprovider

  // Create a balloon Content provider for the world layer
  smallWorldLayer.balloonContentProvider = contentProvider("COUNTRY: ", "name");

  //#snippet ballooncontentprovider
  // Create a balloon content provider for the cities layer, which creates HTML
  // for cities with more than 1.000.000 inhabitants and uses the "default"
  // content provider if not.
  var citiesDefaultProvider = contentProvider("CITY: ", "CITY");
  citiesLayer.balloonContentProvider = function(o) {
    var cityProps = o.properties, node;
    if (cityProps.TOT_POP > 1000000) {
      node = document.createElement("ul", {});
      for (var key in cityProps) {
        if (cityProps.hasOwnProperty(key) && key !== "uid") {
          var item = document.createElement("li");
          item.innerHTML = key + ": " + cityProps[key];
          node.appendChild(item);
        }
      }
      return node;
    } else {
      return citiesDefaultProvider(o);
    }
  };
  //#endsnippet ballooncontentprovider

  //fit on the cities layer
  var queryFinishedHandle = citiesLayer.workingSet.on("QueryFinished", function() {
    //#snippet layerFit
    map.mapNavigator.fit({
      bounds: citiesLayer.bounds,
      animate: true
    });
    //#endsnippet layerFit
    queryFinishedHandle.remove();
  });
```

**Environment**

webpack version:  4.40.2

Node.js version: 10.16.3

Operating System: Windows 10

Any idea what's going on or how to fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe [this comment](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1314#issuecomment-443068600) is helpful?

Comment: @bdbdbd : This library and its samples are only supposed to be run in the browser. They don't use jsdom or node-canvas and I don't think they're supposed to, as these are used to add DOM support to JavaScript that's run on the server, right?